# Ajax call to same page is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am getting records from database in WordPress then creating and adding value in select tag(HTML) dynamically.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$registeredUsers = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_login != "Admin"',ARRAY_A);
$select='<select name="users" class="form-control" id="users">';
    $select.= '<option value="Select User"> Select User</option>';
         foreach($registeredUsers as $user)
         {
            $select.='<option value="'.$user['user_email'].'">'.$user['user_login'].'</option>';
         }
   $select.='</select>';
?>
```

I am using $select variable in Html and drop down is being displayed properly.

```
<form id="a" action="" method="post">
<div style="margin: 0 auto;width:500px;">
<?php echo $select ?>
</div>
</form>
```

I have written code to get selected drop down onchange event in jquery. It return success but I am not able to get selected value of dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("select[name='users']").change(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:  $("form#a").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert("SUCCESS");
                }
                });  
        });
        });
</script>
```

Below code return nothing

```
if(isset($_POST['users'])) {
echo $_POST['users'];
}
```

Comment: Why negative. Can you please explain?

Comment: (I didn't downvoted). Can you tell why you are using Ajax just to receive value from select tag? You can simply do $("select[name='users']").change(function () { alert($(this).val()); });

Comment: I need this value in server side (PHP) not in client side(javaquery).

Comment: I think jQuery supports method: "POST" instead of type: "POST"

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: I didn't check AJAX request/response... Library is already included that's why it comes to success block. No errors reported. Yes, I am running this on a web-server.

Comment: what does data contain? I mean you are telling us the alert is working and showing the code that works, but where is the code that you have tried that is not working?

Comment: @David -  Not working code - if(isset($_POST['users'])) {
echo $_POST['users'];
}

Comment: so data returns empty? .... `console.log(data);` -- check your console. As it is your question is unanswerable, you are omitting vital checks that will explain what is happening, i mean have you used ajax before?

Comment: Yes, I used ajax many time in ExtJs andJquery but first time using in WordPress.

Comment: well look its something simple, i'm not going to spend any more time on this, you still haven't given an answer on what data contains, but recheck everything youself, its vital to use the console to check data before and after ajax.  if you can improve the question with information that helps answer it, you might get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set url option to your page in your ajax function:)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("select[name='users']").change(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"yourpage.php"
                data:  $("form#a").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert("SUCCESS");
                }
                });  
        });
        });
</script>
```

replace yourpage.php

Comment: I have tried, But it doesn't work. I think, if you are sending ajax call to same page, then there is no need to set url. (Not sure).

Comment: whats in data of ajax callback function ?

Comment: No, It doesn't work. I used like this - url:"https://www.ezeeshuttle.com/all-reservations/", or url: "AllReservations.php". If both are wrong way then please let me know how to do this.

Comment: add `if (isset($_POST['users'])) {
     echo $_POST['users'];
    return;
}` at the top of your page

Comment: then you could alert data

Comment: I tried by adding this code at top of page but still it doesn't work. I think, there is another way to send ajax call in WordPress. Thanks for your help @B.Kevin

Comment: You're welcome, im sure you can find a better way to do ajax request with wordpress. https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ajax+wordpress